# How to animate a block of content?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using *twitter-bootstrap* framework.

I'm trying to animate a part of the page. First of all enter in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Fkvv/2/)** and before the code below I'll explain the idea.

**HTML**

```
<div id="bluecont" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8 offset2">
             <h1>Hello stackoverflow!</h1>
            <button id="clickhide">Show span</button>
        </div>
        <div id="spanhide" class="span8 offset2">
             <h2>Thanks for the help!</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="redcont" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8 offset2">
             <h3>This would be the rest content of the page</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#spanhide").hide();

    $("#clickhide").click(function () {
        var caption = $(this).text();

        if (caption == "Show span") {
            $("#spanhide").fadeIn("slow");
            $(this).text("Hide span");
        } else {
            $("#spanhide").fadeOut("slow");
            $(this).text("Show span");
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.span8 {
    background: green;
    padding: 20px
}
#bluecont {
    background:blue;
    padding: 20px
}
#spanhide {
    background: yellow;
}
#redcont {
    background: red;
    padding: 20px
}
#clickhide {
    width: 100%;
}
```

---

Well, as you see there, is a span hidden that I show when I press the button. But when it appears the container of color red goes down directly. What I'm trying is to displace it bit a bit until the span hidden has space to appear. And the same when I want to hide it.

May be using a CSS transition? or .animate() function of jQuery? I don't know... I'm looking for the best way to do it so any help or advice would be appreciated.

If you need more information, let me know and I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**here is the code demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Fkvv/7/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#spanhide").hide();

$("#clickhide").click(function () {
    var caption = $(this).text();

    if (caption == "Show span") {
        $("#spanhide").css({opacity:0}).slideDown("slow").animate({opacity:1});
        $(this).text("Hide span");
    } else {
        $("#spanhide").animate({opacity:0}).slideUp("slow");
        $(this).text("Show span");
    }
});

});
```

Comment: You rocks! And is so elegant too. Thanks Rohit!

Comment: And how i'd put an event at the end of the animation? I know how to do it if I use fadeIn() but using this way I'm afraid not... do you know how, please?

Comment: You made my day... it's a shame you can not give more points this response.

Answer (score 0):

Animate would be good, just add the height of the span first to the container div and animate.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#spanhide").hide();

        $("#clickhide").click(function () {
            var caption = $(this).text();

            if (caption == "Show span") {

                $('.row').animate({
                    height:'+='+ ($('#spanhide').height() + 20)+'px'  
                });

                $("#spanhide").fadeIn("slow");
                $(this).text("Hide span");
            } else {
                $("#spanhide").fadeOut("slow");
                $(this).text("Show span");
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: @Joëlle has flicker in closing / hiding of yellow span

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is using [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) function.

Here is an fiddle which demostrates it: **http://jsfiddle.net/5Fkvv/9/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#spanhide").hide();

    $("#clickhide").click(function () {
        $("#spanhide").slideToggle("slow");

        if ($(this).text() == "Show span") {
            $(this).text("Hide span");
        } else {
            $(this).text("Show span");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: if you are having condition to identify something related to collapse or expand using `slideToggle` doesn't make sense.